# Create a table from json (JSON.stringify(res[0]) ) - output in a string - should be transformed to a table in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, html-table

I need to create a table from JSON, I'm getting output in a string and it should be printed in table format in HTML

```
function apicall(){

        var id = document.getElementById('idval').value;


        var url1 = '**********************';
        var token = sessionStorage.getItem('MyUniqueUserToken');
        var data1 = {"ip":id};
        var success = {};
        var dataType = {};

        $.ajax({
        url: url1,
        data: data1,
        type: "GET",
        beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'token '+token);},
        success: function(res) { 

            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML =JSON.stringify(res[0]);
                               }

  });



}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbwWC.png)

Comment: If you could share a sample response of the API call it would be more helpful. Also how should the result be formatted in the table?

Comment: You can't just set the innerHTML of an element, unless the content is already formatted to represent a table, otherwise you'd have to parse it.

Comment: now data is showing in the data dump, like all the data ina combined form, I need that data to show in a particular table former, like rows and columns where user id in one column and value in another column.

Comment: @ManojDeshmukh could you please `console.log(res)` and copy-paste the output here?

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that res is the response as a JSON so instead of

```
 document.getElementById('output').innerHTML =JSON.stringify(res[0]);
```

you have to put your response into a loop (Given you have an empty table with cells=fields output0 to output4

```
        var i=0;
        response.data.forEach(function(field) {

           //here you create the table cells if there are 5 fields 
             that would be 5 cells as I do not know the structure just 
             pseudo code
             document.getElementById('output'+i).innerHTML = JSON.stringify(res[i]);
             i = i+1;
          }
```

if you want to semi dynamicly create table rows you have to have a table with header (footer) row fix and the tabelbody as an anchor to whichyou append the created rows could look like follows (partly pseudo code) -PLAIN vanilla javascript as I do not like jquery:

```
  // We need a table definition for creating headers and interpreting JSON date
  var tdataRow = [{
        "output0" : field.output0,
        "output1" : field.output1,
        "output2" : field.output2,
        "output3" : field.output3;
       "output4" : field.output4
                    }];
  // Then in jour ajax
  response.data.forEach(function(field) {         
     var columnHeadings = Object.keys(tdataRow[0]);
     var tableRef = document.getElementById("tbody" + "my_test_table");
     var columnCount = 5; // Could be derived from number of headings
     var tableLength = tableRef.getElementsByTagName("tr").length;// we get the number of the existing table rows
 var trowID = tableLength + 1; // we append at the end of existing rows
 var tableRow = tableRef.insertRow(tindex);
 for (var j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) { /* Each column */
    var cell = tableRow.insertCell(-1);
    cell.setAttribute("id", columnHeadings[j] ); 
    var obj = tdataRow[0];
    cell.innerText = obj[columnHeadings[j]]; // we get the field names from the header
 }
 tableRow.setAttribute("id", "row" + "my_test_table" + j );
 // examples how to style and use classes 
 tableRow.classList.add("table");
 tableRow.classList.add("clickable-row");
 tableRow.setAttribute("align","center");
 // if you want to catch clicks on the row
 tableRow.addEventListener("click", function(){
 // do something with the row e.g. highlight/ get values etc
  }
 }
```

The second solution can be converted into a fully automated/dynamic solution where everything is created from the JSON - but small steps first.